# Getting internal Salesforce Error in a SOQL Query

Tags: salesforce

While running a simple salesforce SOQL, getting Internal Salesforce error.

Sample Query :

[Select id, Name, Field_1__c from Custom_Object__c where Case__r.Account != NULL and Custom_Number_Field__c != NULL]

Note : The query was working few days back without any issue. Can someone confirm, if any changes implemented by salesforce recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can raise a salesforce support ticket with the internal salesforce error code.
Second, You can check the optimization of the query by using the following link : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336230&type=1&mode=1
Third, you can make use of Query Plan Tool in Dev Console and see if you need custom indexing